# Angular Js http GET response is displaying in console log but I am not able to display ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

AngularJS HTTP GET response is displaying in console log but I'm not able to display it inside div.  Here is my code I'm beginner I don't figure out why it is not working so I'm asking here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<base href="/">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="test-wallpaper">testing</a>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="newcontroller">
        <div ng-bind-html="resultdata"></div>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute","ngSanitize"]);

            app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
                $routeProvider
                    .when("/:id-wallpaper",{
                        templateUrl: "/new",
                        controller : "newcontroller"
                    });
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            });

            app.controller("newcontroller", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
                $http({
                    url: "new",
                    method: "get",
                    params: { id: $routeParams.id }
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.resultdata = response.data;
                })

            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove `<div ng-bind-html="resultdata"></div>` from your DOM and try to create a `$route`  template. You will also be able create an additional file for your template by using `templateUrl: 'nameOfTemplate.html'` instead of binding it as an HTML-String by using `template` param. Please refer [AngularJS routeProvider configuration](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

#### $route configuration

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/:id-wallpaper",{
            template: '<div>{{ resultdata }}</div>',
            controller : "newcontroller"
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

---

#### With an template file it would look like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/:id-wallpaper",{
            templateUrl: 'myFile.html',
            controller : "newcontroller"
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

#### Content of myFile.html (View)

```
<div>{{ resultdata }}</div>
```

Comment: not working may be there is problem in something else.. if  i put something inside variable manually it is displaying perfeclty inside container $scope.resultdata  = "blabla"; but not to able to  get the same result with http request

Comment: let me try this one thnx for effort

Comment: @Gorki Sorry, I was wrong. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Gorki glad to help ya